# OpenJPA and second level cache (Ehcache)

Tags: java, jpa, ehcache, openjpa

I would like add second level cache for JPA in my project.
I add **ehcache-core** (net.sf.ehcache), add **ehcache-openjpa-0.2.0.jar**.
I have a Entity:

```
@Entity
public class People{
 @Id
 private int ID;

 private String NAME;
...setter and getter...
}
```

In my dao class I have a method:

```
public List<People> getAllCountry(){
 Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT p FROM People p");
 return query.getResultList();
}
```

I add ehcache.xml:

```
<ehcache> 
    <defaultCache 
          maxElementsInMemory="1000" 
          eternal="false" 
          timeToIdleSeconds="300" 
          timeToLiveSeconds="600" 
          overflowToDisk="false" 
          memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" 
          /> 

    <!-- OpenJPA data cache --> 
    <cache name="openjpa" 
                 maxElementsInMemory="5000" 
                 eternal="false" 
                 timeToIdleSeconds="300" 
                 timeToLiveSeconds="600" 
                 overflowToDisk="false" 
                 memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" 
          /> 

    <!-- OpenJPA query cache --> 
    <cache name="openjpa-querycache" 
           maxElementsInMemory="1000" 
           eternal="false" 
           timeToIdleSeconds="300" 
           timeToLiveSeconds="600" 
           overflowToDisk="false" 
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" 
          /> 
</ehcache>
```

in persistance.xml I add:

```
<property name="openjpa.QueryCache" value="ehcache"/> 
<property name="openjpa.DataCacheManager" value="ehcache"/>
```

But then I run query, then I get message:

> Query ".." is removed from cache  excluded premanently. Quer ".." is not cached because its result is not obtained by executing a select statement. This can happen if the query was evaluated in-memory. The result was provided by org.apache.openjpa.datacache.QueryCacheStoreQuery$CachingResultObjectProvider.

How can I fix this problem?